# How to use FieldValue.increment() on the property of an object type document field

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore's `FieldValue.increment(someValue)` is working properly with other fields but not with map.

I am trying to increment the value of a property in a map. I have a document named user. It has a map `points:{id:123, total:100}`. I want to update the value of `total` in map `points`.

```
firestore.collection('users').doc('user').update({
    "name": "atul",
    "points": { "total": firestore.FieldValue.increment(50) }
})
```

Instead of incrementing the `total` value to 150, its value becomes 100.

Comment: Please add your database structure and indicate the exact property you want to incremenet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to call out the full path of the field to increment, not bury it inside an object.  The full path of the field involves using `.` as a separator between the names of each field:

```
firestore.doc(...).update({
    "points.total": firestore.FieldValue.increment(50)
})
```

Comment: Does this work on iOS also? I've tried, but instead of incrementing the map value, it creates a field with a dot.

Comment: I don't know about iOS.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I guess I'll create a separate question!