# iOS Firestore Can `FieldValue.increment` be used for Map values?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to use `FieldValue.increment(_:)` on `Map` field values?

For instance, if you have a field called `foo` whose value is a `Map` type, and inside `foo` is a key-value pair `bar: Int`, can you increment `bar` without using the method in question?

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56427582/how-to-use-fieldvalue-increment-on-the-property-of-an-object-type-document-fie) for JS was asked and the answer was to use `FieldValue.increment(_:)` using the dot notation, like one would use for JS `Object` types; e.g. `points.total`. I've tried this on iOS, but instead of incrementing `bar`, it creates a field `foo.bar` of `Number`.

If possible, it would be great to know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to update a document that looks like this:

```
$docId (document)
  |
  --- foo (map)
       |
       --- bar: 1
```

You **cannot** do it using the `.` (dot) notation:

```
docRef.updateData([
    "foo.bar": FieldValue.increment(Int64(1))
])
```

Because you'll get as a result something that looks like this:

```
$docId (document)
  |
  --- foo.bar: 1
```

So if you want to increment the value of `bar`, you have to use two maps, one to perform the increment operation and one to perform the actual update in Firestore:

```
let increment = [
    "bar": FieldValue.increment(Int64(1))
]
let update = [
    "foo": increment
]
docRef.updateData(update) { err in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error updating document: \(err)")
    } else {
        print("Document successfully updated")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the appropriate answer but since I had a similar problem this might help you, mine was not related to iOS.
If the field's name starts with a number ex. '1test', the map update won't work and the result will be the one you have.

I hope I was helpful.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it starts or not with a number, the update should always work, because all keys in an object are strings.